# Find local IP of a local server via JavaScript client

Tags: javascript, networking, raspberry-pi, ip

I have a Raspberry Pi and a computer, both connected to the same local network (both are connected to the same router, it's **it's not the Pi who is acting as the router**).How can I obtain the local IP address of the Raspberry Pi from a JavaScript script running in the computer (obs: by "client" I mean a JavaScript script running **in the browser**, not a node.js script)? I've thought of two approaches:

First one: To search for all local IPs, which would require the JavaScript client to know both his local IP and the subnet mask of the network, and would essentially try to get (via HTTP or whatever) some response from a specific port on the supposed Raspberry Pi IP address. However, I don't know how reliable that would be in terms of it taking too long to search the network and also of being able to obtain the local IP and subnet mask from the JavaScript client (from what I've read, the local IP is technically obtainable using a fake WebRTC request, even though it looks extremely unreliable; not so sure about the subnet)

Second one: To host a thin third-party server (on some other network) and make the Raspberry Pi server to send its local IP address to the server. When prompted by a request from the client, such third-party server would gracefully tell the Raspberry Pi IP address based on the public IP of the request (multiple requests could be handled from the third-party server, for various local networks).

I don't see why the second approach would not be viable. Is the first approach viable, however? And is there an easier way to solve the problem? Thank you.

Comment: I think you're over complicating it. 1. use [nodejs dns](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html) to lookup the IP address of the raspberryp pi using its hostname - then, 2. use [os.networkInterfaces](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_networkinterfaces) to find the "computer" network addresses, filter for the one in the subnet as step 1. - step 1 will give you the pi IP, step 2 will give you the corresponding computer IP and the net mask for both

Comment: I forgot to mention it is not the Pi who is hosting the network (i.e. acting as a router). I suppose getting the network interfaces from its perspective isn't going to yield the computer's IP address, only its own local IP address.

Comment: it has an IP address, doesn't need to "host the network" to have one

Comment: Oh, you won't be able to do this with javascript running in the browser - well, you may be able to, but that's where you'll need to get into webrtc and all that crap

Comment: basically, if you have a http server running on the pi, then the process is easy ... the pi will have a hostname (raspberrypi by default) so you could access, from javascript in a brower `http://raspberrypi.local` ... and all the info you need will be available to the server side code on the raspberry pi, everything, the pi's address, your address and the cidr/netmask - and it can send it as a response to an AJAX request

Comment: Using the mDNS solved my problem. Write that as an answer and I'll accept it as a correct answer. Thanks! As a bonus, would one be able to get all the Pis connected to the network (different hostnames) via the computer (like, getting <pi1hostname>,local, <pi2hostname>.local ... <pinhostname>.local), all of them)?